# Rank an array: Exclude NaN and assign lowest rank to highest number

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, rank

I have an array/pandas row:

```
array = [0.8, np.nan, 0.1, -0.5, 0.7]
```

I want this output:

```
array = [1, np.nan, 3, 4, 2]
```

These methods are ranking in the wrong direction for me:

```
scipy.stats.mstats.rankdata
scipy.stats.rankdata
```

Comment: If these functions don't support a `reverse` option, simply sort `-array` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you mentioned Pandas, you can use [Series.rank](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.rank.html) method:

```
arr = [0.8, np.nan, 0.1, -0.5, 0.7]
pd.Series(arr).rank(ascending=False)
Out: 
0    1.0
1    NaN
2    3.0
3    4.0
4    2.0
dtype: float64
```

This creates and returns a Pandas Series. If you want to avoid creating a Series, as @ajcr noted in the comments, you can use the rank function. This returns an ndarray:

```
pd.algos.rank_1d_float64(arr, ascending=False)
Out: array([  1.,  nan,   3.,   4.,   2.])
```

Comment: You could also access the rank function more directly and use `pd.algos.rank_1d_float64(array, ascending=False)`, avoiding the overhead of creating a Series (not sure this is part of the public API though).

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach -

```
mask = ~np.isnan(a)
out = np.full(a.size,np.nan)
out[mask] = np.unique(-a[mask],return_inverse=1)[1]+1
```

Sample run -

```
In [48]: a
Out[48]: array([ 0.8,  nan,  0.1, -0.5,  nan,  0.7])

In [49]: out
Out[49]: array([  1.,  nan,   3.,   4.,  nan,   2.])
```